# DynamoDB batch write - massive amount of events

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to insert data to AWS dynmao DB in large batches:
1000, 10000 events at a time.

is this possible?

It only allow me to insert 25 events at a batch.

Regards,
Ido

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple `batchWrite` api calls in parallel.